# KeyError: 'primaryName' with csv.DictReader

Tags: python

first time poster - long time lurker.

I'm a little rough around the edges when it comes to Python and I'm running into an issue that I imagine has an easy fix.

I have a CSV file that I'm looking to read and perform a semi-advanced lookup.

The CSV in question is not really comma delimited when inspecting it in VS Code except the last "column".

Example (direct format screenshot from the file):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcA9e.png)

The line that seems to have issues is:

```
import csv
import sys
from util import Node, StackFrontier, QueueFrontier

names = {}

people = {}

titles = {}

def load_data(directory):

    with open(f"{directory}/file.csv", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
            people[row["id"]] = {
                "primaryName": row["primaryName"],
                "birthYear": row["birthYear"],
                "titles": set()
            }
            if row["primaryName"].lower() not in names:
                names[row["primaryName"].lower()] = {row["nconst"]}
            else:
                names[row["primaryName"].lower()].add(row["nconst"])
```

The error I receive is:

```
  File "C:\GitHub\Project\data-test.py", line 24, in load_data
    "primaryName": row["primaryName"],
                   ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'primaryName'
```

I've tried this with other CSV files where they are comma delimited, (screenshot example below):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebx0P.png)

And that works perfectly fine. I noticed the above CSV file has the names in ""s which I imagine could be part of the solution.

Ultimately, if I can get it to work with the code above that would be great - otherwise, is there an easy way to automatically format the CSV file to put quotations around the names and separate the value by commas like the csv that's working above?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace)?

Comment: Please don’t post images of code, data or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).

[Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: I understand thank you for explaining that to me. The reason I made a screenshot of those was because if I pasted it in the message the format wasn't the same and I wanted to make sure the formatting wasn't the problem.